# SOLR exclude fields in the FL

Tags: solr

Is there a way to tell SOLR that I want all fields to be returned other than several I would like to specify?
I want to get all the fields expect those I want to omit?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is a feature requested very often, but it is not available.

Jiras targeting it (quite old):

- [SOLR-3191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3191) very old
- [SOLR-9467](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9467) newer

Comment: in this case. Is there an API to get all the fields from solr schema and them to get their tzpe so I can filter them?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that,

First in the `schema.xml`, declare your field as `stored="false"` you don't want in your response

```
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Second using the  patch [PATCH](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9467)

It would look something like this:

```
&fl=*,[fl.rm v="title"]
```